# Low Cost Product Photos

Tags: lighting, product-photography

Buying a Canon EOS 2000D.
Building 2 soft light box with some white fabric and cheapo led strips with some dimming circuit.
Building a white paper desk for background

I have some Photoshop and photography skills

Can I shoot decent product photos with that equipment?

My target quality is this:
[image: text]
<sub>(source: [sirv.com](https://weebly.sirv.com/Delivered/Order_1907085_2019-08-05_14-44-16/Lamp_Spin20190730-1.jpg?scale.option=fill&scale.width=1000&quality=60))</sub>

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Regarding your question if the camera is sufficient: Almost any camera will do - more important might be the lens regarding sharpness. And especially a stable tripod. If you use constant light, you will definitely need it.

Answer (score 2):

Cheapo LED strips likely have a bad [Color Rending Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_rendering_index) and you will have color problems. Fluorescent lights are not dimmable(*) but even the cheap ones usually have a good CRI.

(*) electronically, of course, you can always add some cloth, or put it farther away.

Comment: thanks for help. i will research more about lighting. but does canon eos 2000d could be enough with decent lighting.

Answer (score 2):

Cheapo LED strips that are dimmable tend to flicker. That's how they control the overall brightness - by switching on and off rapidly. Many fluorescent light sources also flicker. Your eyes can't see the flickering, but your camera sure will unless you use a longer exposure time ("slow shutter speed").

Cheap LED lights also have parts of the visible spectrum missing from the light they output. This makes getting accurate colors of your products difficult.

If you want to blow the background out to white, you need to make sure the background is lit by a light source brighter than what is illuminating your subject.

There are lots of existing questions here at Photography SE that cover all of this.

[Why can't I get a decent white background with product photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/38343/15871)
[Why hasn't buying powerful lights improved my lightbox images?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/42681/15871)
[Why can't I get a pure white background, even using multiple light sources?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/70185/15871)
[How do I improve the results of photos taken in a light-box?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/40747/15871)
[How many lumens are required to achieve a pure white background in a 40cmx40cm softbox?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/89257/15871)
[How do I properly do shadowless product photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/14991/15871)

For unique issues with triggering flashes due to the non-standard hot shoe on a few entry level Canon EOS cameras (T7/2000D,SL3/250D, T100/4000D/3000D, ), please see:

[Is a Yongnuo YN560-TX compatible with Canon SL3 or T100?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/116582/15871)
[How can I make use of a speedlight that does not work with the non-standard hotshoe on lower-end Canon cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/112954/15871)

Comment: thanks for help. i will research more about lighting. but does canon eos 2000d could be enough with decent lighting.

Comment: If you are using constant lighting (lights that stay on all the time) and placing the camera on a tripod it should do fine. One issue with the Rebel T7/2000D is the non-standard hot shoe that will make it [difficult to trigger flashes that are not Canon E-TTL capable](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/112954/15871), even if you wish to use them in manual flash mode. There are workarounds for some cheaper third party flashes, but you need to be aware of the limitation before you start buying flashes that won't work the way you want with the Rebel T7/2000D.